WxPython Align text in TextCtrl Center Vertical
I am trying to center the text inside a TextCtrl. Many solutions to other similar questions rely on using ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL however I cannot do this as I want my text box to be larger than the font height.
This is what I am trying now:
self.name_tb = wx.TextCtrl(self.showing_panel, style=wx.BORDER_NONE | wx.TE_CENTRE)
self.showing_sizer.Add(self.name_tb, 1, flag=wx.ALIGN_CENTER_VERTICAL | wx.RIGHT, border=3)
self.name_tb.SetMinSize((-1, height))  # height > font height


Desired outcome is that the text and the cursor is aligned vertically centered.
Edit:
Code and Screenshot of runnable code

class MyFrame(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
        self.SetSize((400, 200))
        self.SetTitle("Centre Text Vertically")
        self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)
        sizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        self.text_ctrl = wx.TextCtrl(self.panel, wx.ID_ANY, "", style=wx.TE_CENTRE)
        self.text_ctrl.SetMinSize((150, 50))
        sizer.Add(self.text_ctrl, 0, wx.ALIGN_CENTER_HORIZONTAL | wx.TOP, 40)
        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.Layout()

        wx.CallAfter(self.displayText)

    def displayText(self):
        self.text_ctrl.SetValue("Text Text Text")
        self.text_ctrl.SetInsertionPointEnd()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = wx.App()
    frame = MyFrame(None)
    frame.Show()
    app.MainLoop()

Ran on Mac:

Ran on Linux:

It seems like this is only an issue on Mac. Any ideas?

I don't think its possible. Is this the only control on the form? How do you do the layout? Can you post the whole code and the screenshot?

@Igor added it in via edit, looks like it works on Linux but not Mac

are you running in Dark Mode? What happen if you try the Light mode?

Same thing sadly :/

what is your OS/python/wxPython versions?
